# How to set default value with $elemMatch in Mongoose and Nddejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've route that's suppose to filter my files based on 3 inputs - and that works.

```
app.get("/api/getFiles", (req, res) => {
  let grade = req.query.grade;
  let study = req.query.study;
  let subject = req.query.subject;

  User.find(
    { files: { $elemMatch: { study: study, subject: subject, grade: grade } } },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) res.status(400).send(err);
      res.send(doc);
    }
  );
});
```

However, these inputs are not dependent on one another.

E.G if `grade = 5` function should return files that match specific grade regardless of their `study` or `subject`.

Is there any default value in `$elemMatch` that will, in this case, get all files regardless of their `study` or `subject` ?

Comment: Can you please add sample data and expected output. Much easier to give and test a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default value for $elemMatch, you have to write the custom conditions in the code only

```
app.get("/api/getFiles", (req, res) => {
  let grade = req.query.grade;
  let study = req.query.study;
  let subject = req.query.subject;

  if grade == 5:{
  User.find(
    { files: { $elemMatch: {grade: 5 } } },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) res.status(400).send(err);
      res.send(doc);
    }
  );}
  else: {
  User.find(
    { files: { $elemMatch: { study: study, subject: subject, grade: grade } } },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) res.status(400).send(err);
      res.send(doc);
    }
  );}
});
```

Comment: Are you aware of any better way, maybe with $in or $and ?